# How to pass a field name to the global message in the properties file

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization, resourcebundle, properties-file

I have the following message in my global-messages.properties file.

```java
errors.integer=${getText(fieldname)} must be an integer.
```

which works fine with the validation.xml code, but I want to be able use the same message in my java action validation method with the `addFieldError()` method.  My question is how to pass the `fieldname` to the message.  If I use:

```java
addFieldError("seqId", getText("errors.integer"));
```

I only get the "must be an integer." part of the message.  I know I could change the message and use `{0}` instead of `${getText(fieldname)}` but that is not an option because other code uses the message as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: You should really avoid using `getText` in properties because it is available only in some context.

Second: You should really avoid using `fieldname` in properties because it is validator specific field.

To achieve what you want, w/o modifying property file, you can create a `fieldname` property in your action with getter/setter and set its value before using `addFieldError`.

```java
private String fieldname;
// getter/setter

// ...
fieldname = "seqId";
addFieldError("seqId", getText("errors.integer"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  When I move up in the decision making process I will try to remember your two warnings.  Right now those decisions have already been made.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Someone else showed me another way which worked which I thought I would share.

```
addFieldError("",getText("seqId")+ getText("errors.integer"));
```